# why are config files written in commonJS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I have recently used gatsby and webpack's explicit implementation . Files which are complied by webpack or React files are written in ES6 while some files like config.js , gatsby-node.js are  written in commonJS and have module.exports and require . I have doubt regarding  the environment being same for same project and interpretation  is different for different files . webpack.config.js file is also written in commonJS .

Comment: the files written in commonjs are being read directly through node, whereas the files written in es6 are being loaded through webpack (aka run through babel)

Comment: then why webpack can't read it's config file or gatsby its node api file through babel first if they both have webpack support ?

Comment: React doesn't have a config file? Or have I missed something...

Comment: webpack has to run _on node_ so all of the files that get read _before_ webpack has started needs to be non-babel. `node -> webpack -> app`

Comment: @evolutionxbox gatsby has config files

Comment: thanks , @azium . I was also having the same thought of behind the scenes . One more query, why does node environment does not have babel  support till date ?

Comment: it makes no sense for node to have babel support, babel runs _on node_ not the other way around. that being said node does support new syntaxes and continues to add support for them such as `import` but they are in newer versions https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html